# Push data into array's specific index after asynchronous request from server

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I've an object and I push that into main array just when document is loaded, now after response from server data is pushed into specific arrays which are nested into main array.

I have tried making a new instance of `MainData` each time when I want to push into array, but object name has to be same (as there are lot of requests and all of them has to be asynchronous) that is why it is mixing up values.

I am doing right now:

```
// Knockout viewModel
function ViewModel() {
    self = this
    self.main_array = ko.observableArray([])
}
var pointer = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBidings(pointer);
// Constructor for dummy data
function MainData() {
    self = this
    self.id = ko.observable()
    self.first_val = ko.observableArray()
    self.second_val = ko.observableArray()
}
var main_data;
// Main function which is called when document is loaded
num_type = (data) => { // data is 1234
    main_data = new MainData();
    main_data["id"] = data;
    pointer.main_array.push(main_data);

    // Fetch Requests
    fetch("Num/Func1").then(x => {
        x.json().then(b => {
            main_data.first_val(b);
            char_type(b[0].char); // this has to be called once b is loaded
        })
    })
    // Another fetch request which gives a little late response
    fetch("Num/Func2").then(x => {
        x.json().then(b => {
            // It takes 10 plus seconds meanwhile char_type function has fetched data
            main_data.second_val(b);
        })
    })
}

// char_type function
char_type = (data) => { // data is abc
    main_data = new MainData();
    main_data["id"] = data;
    pointer.main_array.push(main_data);

    // Fetch Request
    fetch("Char/Func1").then(x => {
        x.json().then(b => {
            main_data.first_val(b); // This response comes before fetch to 'Num/Func2' 
        })
    })
    fetch("Char/Func2").then(x => {
        x.json().then(b => {
            main_data.second_val(b); // This response also comes before fetch to 
            //'Num/Func2' 
        })
    })
}
```

The values from both indices mixed together i.e index that is having `main_data.id = 123` carries data from index which is having `main_data.id = abc`

Also There are some server calls which are outside `num_type` and `char_type` function.

How to get rid of that mixing stuff?

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the declaration of `main_edata` *inside* the function, so you get a different, local copy each time the function is called. Then, the `fetch` callbacks will close over the local copy related to the `num_type`/`char_type` call that triggered that specific `fetch`.

Change this:

```
var main_data;
// Main function which is called when document is loaded
num_type = (data) => { // data is 1234
    main_data = new MainData();
    // ...
}
```

to this:

```
// Main function which is called when document is loaded
num_type = (data) => { // data is 1234
    var main_data = new MainData(); // <====== Note `var`
    // ...
}
```

And add `var` before `main_data` in `char_type`, too.

Comment: But all the fetch requests are not inside `num_type` function, I am sorry I forget to mention in question

Comment: @MuhammadMudassar - That's why I said you had to declare it in `char_type`, too. Or if you want `char_type` to use the same `main_data` that `num_type` does, have `num_type` pass it to `char_type`. I'd help more, but I can't tell from the code what it's meant to do.

Comment: Alright, but problem is that the server calls are not in `char_type` neither in `num_type` they are in other functions and I cannot create main_data again and again for each server call, `num_type` and `char_type` are just entry points

Comment: @MuhammadMudassar - You appear to have an array of `main_data` objects. What rules determine when you create a new one vs. when you reuse an existing one? Your `num_type` and `char_type` code is creating a new one every time, which is why I suggested making them local. But it sounds like you want to reuse them sometimes. What are the rules? :-)

Comment: New object of `main_data` can be created in `num_type` and `char_type` but I want to use that object in another function say `new_type`, I want to have track of the object in `new_type` so that I can know if it is with the `id = 123` OR `id=abc`

Comment: So sorry I don't know how to explain this precisely :p

Comment: @MuhammadMudassar - To do that, you'll have to pass it to `new_type` as an argument.

Comment: If there is any other option? Because there are more then 300 functions :'(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197043/discussion-between-muhammad-mudassar-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: @MuhammadMudassar - (I don't do chat when it's relevant to the question.) If there are more than 300 functions interacting with your `main_array`, you probably need to do some refactoring. If you can use `async` and `await`, you can probably use a global, but if you can't, the equivalent using promise syntax will be **really** ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create local variable for each main function and then pass that to other functions.
like:

```
num_type = (data) => {
  var  main_data = new MainData();
 other_fun(data,main_data)
}
```